# source code for F# 3.0 talk on BUILD

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

is there a dowload link for the source code in [Don Syme's F#3.0 talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-904T) on //build/?

Comment: I haven't heard his talk, but [this](http://fsharpsamples.codeplex.com/) includes some 3.0 samples.

Comment: Oops, posted the wrong link. It should be http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source code of the examples from the talk on his blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/10/05/demo-scripts-from-the-f-3-0-build-talk.aspx